# WEIRD: jquery .show and .hide not responding or changing css of corresponding div

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Sample Code of my error](http://playerspace.com/test.html)

So as you can see in the above example, next to where it says "Disclaimer Question111", there is an expand/contract link. The script works halfway, in that the text change occurs, but it does not change the display css for the div its anchored to.

Any idea why? I don't see any page errors.

The code that triggers this is in my site.js file but i pulled it out here so you can see:

```
    $('.accordion-trigger-settings').click(function(){
var target=$(this).attr('href');
if($(target).css('display')=='none')
{
$(target).show();
$(this).text('Collapse Settings');
}
else
{
$(target).hide();
$(this).text('Expand Settings');
}
return false;
});
```

It applies to this block:

```
<a href="#accordion-season5160" class="accordion-trigger-settings">Expand View</a>
                                <div class="padding5"></div> 
                                <div class="accordionContent" id="accordion-season5160">
                                    <textarea  name="str_disclaimer_header5160" id="str_disclaimer_header5160"></textarea>
                                </div>
```

Comment: What is the name of the script containing snippet on the page you provided? Are you sure it is loaded? The code is working fine for me http://jsbin.com/itucop/1/edit

Comment: its in site.js. I know! I can't explain it either! The script works fine on another page. Something about this page is causing it to break and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Chrome web inspector I see you have two elements with id `accordion-season5160`. So, the text is changing because it applies to `this` but the `show()` method is modifying (showing/hiding) the first element with id `accordion-season5160`.

Make sure the id is unique.

See the image!

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: If you view the source you will see there is only one element with an ID of accordion-season5160. One is a LINK to #accordion-season5160, the other is the ID of accordion-season5160.

Comment: See image: two ID and two LINK.

Comment: Firbug shows the same thing: two divs with the id _accordion-season5160_.  This is why it's helpful to use a debugger: you can quickly inspect the value of things like `$(target)` to see how many elements they contain.

Comment: I see two also. It looks like the other one is in some hidden tab view.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have two `<div id="accordion-season5160"...>` on the page. One of them is hidden (inside hidden `<div class="hide_div">`).
You can find them both using console:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#accordion-season5160')
```

You will see both of them. To see the element you can right click on it in the console and click 'Reveal in elements panel' (in Chrome)

The best way to solve this issue is to make `id`s unique. However you can try a quick way to solve the issue that does not require uniqueness of `id`s:

Replace

```
var target=$(this).attr('href');
```

with

```
var target=this.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling;
```

JS Bin http://jsbin.com/itucop/1/edit